# What was the IVP?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

> **When the Laplace Transform is applied to a certain IVP, the resulting equation is $(s^2Y - 2s - 1) + (sY - 2)- 2Y = \frac{4}{s}$**
>
> **What was the IVP?**

So I think I've solved this, but just want to make sure I got the correct answer.

I got:

$y(0) = 2$ , $y'(0) = 1$, & $C = 2$

$\therefore y'' + y' - 2y = 4$ was the IVP correct?

Comment: Initial Value Problem

Comment: What's $C$ ?...

Comment: The $C$ is the constant multiplied by the $Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\underbrace{(s^2Y - 2s - 1)}_{\mathcal{L}(y'') = s^2 \mathcal{L}(y) - s y(0) - y'(0)} + 
\underbrace{(sY - 2)}_{\mathcal{L}(y') = s \mathcal{L}(y) - y(0)} - 
2\underbrace{Y}_{\mathcal{L}(y)} = 
\underbrace{\frac{4}{s}}_{\mathcal{L}(4 H)}
$$
So $y(0) = 2$ and $y'(0) = 1$ fit. And the untransformed ODE was
$$
y''+ y' - 2y = 4 H = 4
$$
as we only consider $y$ for non-negative arguments. (Note: $H$ is the Heaviside step function)

If $C$ means the coefficient for $y$ in the ODE, then I would set $C = -2$.

Comment: Yeah but how would you know if $C=-2$ or not? What if the equation originally was $y'' + y' - (Cy) = 4$ then you would screw it up because then it would turn into $y'' + y' + 2y =4$ which isn't correct right?

Comment: Also why aer you putting a $4H$ in there? The LaPlace inverse of 4/s is just simply 4..Why the heaviside function? It seems unnecesarry

Comment: The transform of $y'' + y' - (Cy) = 4$ is $(s^2 Y-2s-1)+(sY-2)-CY = 4/s$. But the given transform has no explicit $C$ given. As coefficient of $y$ it is $-2$ in the transformed ODE and the original ODE.

Comment: Regarding $H$: Habit. You can ignore it.